# Lifetime of lambda captures

Tags: c++, lambda

Given the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> i(new int(42));
    cout << i.use_count() << endl;
    auto fn = [=](){i; cout << 42 << endl;};
    cout << i.use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When does the compiler decide which objects it will capture?
The shared_ptr `i` is never used in the lambda expression. So in a normal function I would assume that the optimizer will remove this nop statement.
But if it is removed the compiler could think that `i` needs not to be captured.

So with gcc this program will always produce 1,2 as an output.
But is this guaranteed by the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we go to cppreference page on [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) they have the following explanation:

> [=] captures all automatic variables mentioned in the body of the lambda by value

and further says:

> The capture-list is a comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally beginning with the capture-default. The only capture defaults are & (implicitly catch the odr-used automatic variables and this by reference) **and = (implicitly catch the odr-used automatic variables and this by value).**

The reference section for [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) says:

> a variable is odr-used if its name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression, except if all of the following is
>   true:
>
> - applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to the exression yields a constant expression that doesn't invoke non-trivial functions
> - the expression is either discarded-value expression or an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion

The exceptions do not apply to `i` so `i` will be captured.

Which agrees with the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `5.1.2` *Lambda expressions* paragraph *11* which says:

> If a lambda-expression has an associated capture-default and its
>   compound-statement odr-uses (3.2) this or a variable with automatic
>   storage duration and the odr-used entity is not explicitly captured,
>   then the odr-used entity is said to be implicitly captured; such
>   entities shall be declared within the reaching scope of the lambda
>   expression.

Answer (score 2):

With a default-capture of `[=]`, any local variable is captured if it's *odr-used* within the lambda. The definition of *odr-used* is:

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is *odr-used* unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied.

Here, `i` is an evaluated expression, and isn't a constant; so it is `odr-used` and therefore is captured; whether or not evaluating the expression has any effect.

> But is this guaranteed by the standard?

tl;dr yes.